# Why with float datatype cause true?

Tags: c++

```
float x, y, z;
    x = 0.1;
    y = 0.2;
    z = 0.3;
    if (x + y == z)
        cout << "True" << endl;
    else
        cout << "False" << endl;
```

I read a question that says 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3 -> false, when I changed it into variables. It caused true. Why this happens?

Comment: @NathanOliver The question was talking about "false".

Comment: floats are imprecise, and so directly checking the equivalence of floats is generally a bad idea. If you want to see if the sum of `x` and `y` is within a certain range of `z`, try something like checking if `abs((x+y)-z) < 0.0001` or some other appropriate tolerance value. Preferably find a way to not have to rely on float comparisons, though.

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez What's the difference between storing them in float variables and comparing them directly w/o variables?

Comment: I see, I get your question now. I genuinely don't know the answer to that. It probably has something to do with the compiler optimization. In my version of Visual Studio it is true in debug and false in release.

Comment: You should generally avoid comparisons with `==` and `!=` for floating point values. Prefer `<=`, `>=`, `<`, `>` or compare for equality in a way that takes a reasonably sized epsilon into account.